# Spring changed session values

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session

In Spring application, I need to hold user value until I don't remove or destroy.

According to it, I have used the HttpSession in the Controller as follows

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/search" }, method = RequestMethod.POST) //this hander called once
public String search(SearchVo aSearchVo, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model,HttpSession httpsession) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("searches", new SearchVo());
        return "home";
    }       
    httpSession.setAttribute("searchstring", aSearchVo.getSearchString());

    return "caseResult";
}



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = { "/filtersearch" }, method = RequestMethod.POST) //This handler call again and again
public String filterSearch(@ModelAttribute("filter") FilterVo fvo,ModelMap model , HttpSession httpSession){

         String searchKeyWorld=httpSession.getAttribute("searchstring");
             System.out.println(searchKeyWorld);

             searchKeyWorld+=fvo.getFilterWorld();

    return "caseResult";
  } 
}
```

but in the session variable, the value gets changed automatically as in the last filter; as I haven't set any session variable in filtersearch Handler

Comment: i haven't understood your question properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @SessionAttributes for putting variable in http session.
This is a class level annoation.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("searches")
public class MyController{

@RequestMapping(value = { "/search" }, method = RequestMethod.POST) //this hander called once
public String search(SearchVo aSearchVo, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model,WebRequest webRequest) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("searches", new SearchVo());
        return "home";
    }       
    model.addAttribute("searches", new SearchVo());
   //For removing anything from session
   //webRequest.removeAttribute("searches", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
    return "caseResult";
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try reading variable like (SearchVo)webRequest.getAttribute("Session variable name", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION); And use Model in place of ModelMap